# Error deploying asp.net mvc 3 projects to Windows Azure web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an `asp.net mvc 3` project and a separate `BusinessLayer` project included in the solution. When I'm trying to deploy my site to Azure via local git repository, I'm getting the following error: `'<remote_path>\BusinessLayer\BusinessLayer.csproj' is not a deployable project.`. No other information is provided in logs. Site perfectly deploys on my local server. So I want to know at least some possible reasons why this error occurs. Thanks in advance.

Here's my .csproj file, if necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{31F2F6FE-10D8-4510-AC61-CBE1962D3940}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>BusinessLayer</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>BusinessLayer</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Bson">
      <HintPath>..\..\Libs\MongoDB.Bson.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Driver">
      <HintPath>..\..\Libs\MongoDB.Driver.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Battle.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BattleManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BattlePlace.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ConvertHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ImageHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Message.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Picture.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Place.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PlaceManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Subject.cs" />
    <Compile Include="User.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\DBHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to tell Azure exactly which project it should deploy, which you can do using a .deployment file at the root of your project. e.g.

```
[config]
project = WebProject/WebProject.csproj
```

Please see [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to deploy the BusinessLayer project and not the Website project.  As long as your MVC site project has a reference to BusinessLayer, just deploy the website.  BusinessLayer will be included as a reference.
You can't deploy BusinessLayer by itself, as it is a library and not an application.